# How to find specific sql query in a c# project

Tags: c#, sql-server, full-text-search, search-engine

I am working on a very long c# code that i have not been in process of writing it. But I have everything needed (like i have exactly the same databases they used).

I want to find that specific part where they initially access the data from database. They have 5 databases and about 200 database connections. But I need the query for a special column in special DB table. I know the column name which I want to look for.

How can I find that part of code in that project? or what about ctrl+shift+f? Thank you and sorry for long question :)

Comment: ctrl+shift+f will allow you to search throughout the solution including all c#, aspx, .html, .chtml, css files...

you can use ctrl+shift+f and look for specific keywords or in your case column name you have in DB

Comment: Hello guys thank you for your answers. The code i am working on consists of ~100 classes each class has around 2k-3k lines. i tried to search my table name in the code but i could not find any lines except some comment lines. and comments were not to inform me. anyways i wanted to find it cuz they seem they name a .txt file from that database. luckily i found where they name files. (searched for ".txt" " ;) ) but still that db table naming can be a problem for me. is it possible they dont use table names in a query at all? i know they are using a table named as "t_doc". Thx for helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely `ctrl+shift+f` will be useful to find the column with it's name as far as **inline queries** are written in the code but if the code uses **Stored-Procedures** for accessing data then you will have to check each Stored-Procedure in each Database.